# jQuery image PULSE animation on mouseover, fades to another image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, pulse

I'm trying to make an effect where on mouseover the image pulses between two different files in jQuery. I have the beginning written, but I'm struggling with the actual animation part.

Here is what I have so far. I know that I need to write something that tells the image to fade into the next image and then fades back. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.pulse_image = null;
        window.pulse_continue_loop = false;

        $('.pulse').mouseover(function() {
            // User is hovering over the image.
            window.pulse_continue_loop = true;
            window.pulse_image = $(this);

            PulseAnimation(); // start the loop     
        }).mouseout(function() {
            window.pulse_continue_loop = false;
            window.pulse_image.stop();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I'm hoping to do something similar to this where it would be easy to apply to multiple images - having two images, one example_off.jpg and example_on.jpg.

```
jQuery(function(){
            $(".img-swap").hover(
                function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");},
                function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't necessarily need a plugin to do this.  Lets say you have an image tag like

```
<img id = "image" src = "/path/to/front_image" data-alternate = "/path/to/back_image" width = "50" height = "50" />
```

You can set the `data` attribute to hold the path to the alternate image, and implement a swap like

```
//bind mouse events to image element with a given function
$("img#image").on("mouseover", function(e){
                imageSwap($(e.currentTarget));  
               })
               .on("mouseout", function(e){                 
                 imageSwap($(e.currentTarget));
               });

function imageSwap(image){
   //get the alternate source image as a placeholder
   var newSource = image.data("alternate"); 

   //save the image's current source in the data attribute
   image.data("alternate", image.attr("src"));

   //execute fadeOut operation of the image
   image.fadeOut("fast", function(e){

     //replace the image source attribute with the new image source
     image.attr("src") = newSource;

     //execute the fadeIn operation to show the new image
     image.fadeIn("fast");
   }); 
}
```

What this allows you to do is bind the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to a single function that swaps the image source attributes with a `data` variable and executes a fadeOut and fadeIn operation in sequence.

Comment: Hmm, the image appears to just disappear off the page when this is implemented.